# Why child class doesn't overwerite the fields from based class in python and how deal with that

Tags: python

I create based abstract class in python which is based class for all child classes and implement some functions which will be redundant to write each time in every child class.

```
class Element:

    ###SITE###
    __sitedefs = [None]

    def getSitedefs(self):
        return self.__sitedefs


class SRL16(Element):

    ###SITE###
    __sitedefs = ['SLICEM']
```

Ther result is logical in on hand beacuse I get the value from the based class where I declare the value but otherwise I overwite it in child one. My question is how to get from

```
srl = SRL16()
srl.getSitedefs()
```

SLICEM not NONE

Probably I missunderstending something very based but please help.

Best regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem's is due to name mangling. See eg: [What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python).

If you change all the `__sitedefs` by `_sitedefs` then everything should work as expected.

Comment: Indeed, this is the entire purpose of the double-leading underscore.